# What's the purpose of setting NODE_ENV on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, ghost-blog, openshift-client-tools

After installing ghost on Openshift why is it required to type these commands ?

```
rhc set-env NODE_ENV=production --app $appname
rhc app restart $appname
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Ghost's skeleton [`config.js`](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/config.example.js) module, you will notice there are several discreet sections, such as `development`, `test`, `production`, that specify the settings for each runtime environment.

By default, most Node.js applications will run in `development` mode unless `NODE_ENV` is explicitly configured otherwise. Since Ghost is a Node.js application, it too respects `NODE_ENV` in order to configure runtime settings.

You should definitely not be running your Ghost server in production with the default `development` runtime environment.